# How do I get the RGBA value of a certain pixel in the screen in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, rgba

I am making an app where I need to find the RGBA value of the bottom left pixel on the screen and then save it so that I can set it as the color value of a certain Image View. How can I do this?

Comment: You want the color within your app or outside of your app

Comment: @Fangming I want the color within my app

Comment: @BobSamuels you want to find the color of the pixel at (0, height). don't you?